# vs2003: identify first row in DataRow[]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003, datarow

what is the best way to identify first row in the following code?

```
foreach(DataRow row in myrows)
{

if (first row )
{
...do this...
}
else
{
....process other than first rows..
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag for this:

```
bool isFirst = true;

foreach(DataRow row in myrows)
{
    if (isFirst)
    {
        isFirst = false;
        ...do this...
    }
    else
    {
        ....process other than first rows..
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... @Adam, I´m sure that you answered this with a good reason. I'm curious to know why is better to use a boolean that check if the row index == 0. Is more eficient? thanks! :-)

Comment: @Javier: Do you mean calling `Array.IndexOf(myrows, row) == 0`? If so, then yes, this is absolutely more efficient. If you want to know the index, then Hunter's solution using a `for` loop would be more advisable. If you're referring to `row.Index`, then that's its index within its parent `DataTable`, *not* within the array that he describes.

Answer (score 3):

you could just use a for loop instead

```
for(int i = 0; i < myrows.Count; i++) 
{
    DataRow row = myrows[i];
    if (i == 0) { }
    else { }
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Index == 0)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: He indicates that he has a `DataRow[]`, not a `DataTable`. There's no necessary correlation between a row's index in a table and its index within an arbitrary array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a int to loop through the collection.

```
for (int i =0; i < myDataTable.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    if (i ==0)
    {
       //first row code here
    }
    else
    {
       //other rows here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the DataRow to DataRowView:

[How Can Convert DataRow to DataRowView in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632036/how-can-convert-datarow-to-datarowview-in-c-sharp)

and after that:

```
    foreach (DataRowView rowview in DataView)
{
    if (DataRowView.Table.Rows.IndexOf(rowview.Row) == 0)
    {
        // bla, bla, bla... 
    }
}
```